# SQL Query for a Total Amount between Date Range

Tags: sql

Problem: I want to return the Total Amount of Invoices created in the 1st 15 days from when the generated their 1st Invoice

Invoice Table:

```
ClientID  InvoiceDate  InvoiceAmt
--------  -----------  ----------
150       1/15/2012    150
150       1/25/2012    1200
150       2/10/2012    800
250       1/12/2012    950
250       1/26/2012    1050
250       2/05/2012    1250
400       1/10/2012    500
400       1/26/2012    700
```

So the 1st Invoice created for each is the following:

```
150 = 1/15/2012
250 = 1/12/2012
400 = 1/10/2012
```

Now I want to calculate 15 Days out from the Initial Invoice Date. So the calculation should return:

```
150 = 1/30/2012
250 = 1/27/2012
400 = 1/25/2012
```

Now I would like the query to Sum the InvoiceAmt for the appropriate date range.

```
150 = 1350
250 = 2000
400 = 500
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: What RDBMS and version are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following (See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/83354/1)):

```
select i1.clientid
    , sum(invoiceamt) as Total
from invoice i1
inner join
(
    select clientid, min(invoicedate) mindate
    from invoice i
    group by clientid 
) i2
    on i1.clientid = i2.clientid
where i1.invoicedate between i2.mindate and dateadd(d, 15, mindate)
group by i1.clientid
```

Comment: Generally speaking, it's better to use explicitly defined ranges, especially in the case of dates - use 'lower-bound inclusive, upper-bound exclusive'.  This is especially true if timestamps are being used, as attempting to use inclusive ranges becomes non-trivial.

Comment: @X-Zero true, it depends on the data.  Based on what what given there are not issues with timestamp though.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and solving my problem. Liking SQL Fiddle

Comment: @MichaelW SQL Fiddle is great for posting data for questions.