# Find all data in date range then calculate total per month

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table in which each record has a `startDateTime` and a `finishDateTime`. I want to be able to return the total time in each month.

My current query is this:

```
$dateRange = "BETWEEN '$startDate' AND '$finishDate'"; 

$sql = 
"SELECT 
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, StartDateTime, FinishDateTime) As Duration,
    StartDateTime As Start, FinishDateTime As Finish
FROM Entries
WHERE StartDateTime $dateRange AND FinishDateTime $dateRange";
```

Table Entries

```
| StartDateTime       | FinishDateTime |
| 2016-08-18 10:00:00 | 2016-08-18 11:00:00 |
| 2016-08-18 12:00:00 | 2016-08-18 14:00:00 |
| 2016-08-31 17:00:00 | 2016-09-01 09:00:00 |

Desired Output
| Month               | Duration       |
| Aug                 | 10             |
| Sept                | 9              |
```

which will return the duration of each record but not the total for each month. What do I need to add to or change in this query to get the required data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Query for a Total Amount between Date Range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616693/sql-query-for-a-total-amount-between-date-range)

Comment: post current output as opposed to desired output as well as db schema and possibly an sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Please edit the question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

Supposedly that every entry is started and finished in the same month try the following:

```
$sql = 
    "SELECT 
        SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, StartDateTime, FinishDateTime)) As Duration
    FROM Entries
    WHERE 
        YEAR(StartDateTime) = YEAR(FinishDateTime) 
        AND MONTH(StartDateTime) = MONTH(FinishDateTime)
        AND StartDateTime $dateRange 
        AND FinishDateTime $dateRange
    GROUP BY MONTH(StartDateTime)";
```

Comment: How would you cater for a record which went from the end of one month into the beginning of the next?

Comment: You can check if the month and year is the same for StartDateTime and FinishDateTime. Check updated answer.

Comment: You are right. I didn't submit the changes. Check again.

Comment: That doesn't appear to work.
With the date range part as 
AND StartDateTime BETWEEN '2016-08-02 00:00:00' AND '2016-09-02 23:59:59' 
 AND FinishDateTime BETWEEN '2016-08-02 00:00:00' AND '2016-09-02 23:59:59'
I get 19 hours in august instead of the 10 in Aug and 9 in Sept as desired

Comment: The current query in the answer provides the total hours for entries that have started and finished the same month. It prints 3 hours for August. I think that what you want is way more complex than this.